# SVG animate don't work for the first loading [firefox]

Tags: css, firefox, svg, svg-animate

I need loading animation for my page, thats why i found [this page (loading.io)](http://loading.io/).

You can create your own animation and export to `css`/`gif`/`svg`. I downloaded **`SVG`**.

I added everything to project - this is my piece of code:

```
.something{
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(img/rolling.svg);
}
```

And now i have a problem. When i open page for the **first time** (or reload browser cache) animation don't work - I can see `background-image` but animation cannot start. For the second time it's working correctly but what about the first time? **How can I fix it?**

I checked google chrome - everything is ok. **It seems it only appears on firefox.**

Firefox version: **47.0.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed from Firefox version 50 by [bug 935888](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=935888).

Comment: Cool! Thank you for fix! Meh, firefox 50.. it's end of 2016.. so long. Anyway I'm glad that it was finally repaired.